# Store items in SESSION from array on link click

Tags: php, html

I currently have a table populated from an array.
The issue i'm having is storing the products on "Add to Cart"

```
    <?php
session_start();
$products = array(
array('SKU'=>'test1', 'name'=>'ProductTest1', 'Price'=>10.00),
array('SKU'=>'test2', 'name'=>'ProductTest2', 'Price'=>11.00),
array('SKU'=>'test3', 'name'=>'ProductTest3', 'Price'=>12.00)
);

if(isset($_GET['action' && $_get['action'] == "addToCart"))
{
$id = $_GET['product']);
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){
$_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
}
else
{


?>
```

Below is also the table php which populates correctly.

```
<?php foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $product['SKU'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $product['name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . '&pound;'. number_format($product['Price'],2) . '</td>';
echo '<td><a href="?action=addToCart&product='. $key.'">Add To Cart </a></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

I can't figure out how to store the name and price of the items using the GET function, which should take the value from the URL.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you looking for something other than `$products[$id]['name']`?

Comment: I'm looking to store 'name' and 'price' to be displayed on another page in a summary style page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the element from `$products` into the session variable to get the name, SKU, and price.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $products[$id];
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'] = 1;
}
```

Now other scripts can access `$_SESSION['cart'][$id]['name']` and `$_SESSION['cart'][$id]['Price']`.

Another option would be to put the `$products` definition in an include file, which is loaded by the other page to get this information.

Eventually you'll probably want to put your product information in a database, which could be accessed by both pages.

Comment: Thankyou very much.
Ideally yes, all the product information should be in a database so that it can be queried, however as you can tell i'm very new to PHP so just trying to grasp the concepts for now!
Now that the id's are stored in the SESSION variable, how might I go about transferring the stored items onto cart.php for summary display?

Comment: That's what my answer does. I've added a little more detail.